# Use dynamic popups with css / bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of items and every item can trigger a popup (the "normal" one from here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/00eAd).
My problem: When I add them dynamically, they won't fire (i.e.: Nothing happens). I'm using the popups within angular2

HTML of item:

```
<div class="resultitem-overlay container" *ngIf="showOverlayItemOption">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <a href="#_{{ index }}" class="play" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup_{{ index }}"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
                ...
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

HTML of popup:

```
<div id="popup_{{ index }}" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
      <pm-popup></pm-popup>
</div>
```

The {{ index }} ist just a placeholder and is replaced by the index of each item to get a real id.

CSS:

```
.modal-dialog {
  padding: 0px ;
  position: relative; 
}
.modal-dialog:before {
  content: '';
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: -14px;
  z-index: 99;
 }

 .modal-dialog .close {
   z-index: 99999999;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
   font-weight: normal;
   top: 4px;
   right: 6px;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 1;
 }

 .custom-modal-header .modal-title {
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 .modal-dialog:after {
   content: '';
   height: 0px;
   width: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 1px;
   right: -14px;
   z-index: 999999;
 }
```

It "works" when I use the html id without {{index}} (i.e. "popup") but that way I can't show the popups dynamically.

Comment: Have you used `ng-repeat` ? `{{index}}` works only inside `ng-repeat`. - Why don't you simply check in the DOM using developer tool, what values of `{{index}}` are being generated.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa: I'm setting {{ index }} via ngFor and it is correctly interpolated (at least in the DOM). But the MatWaligora gave the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data target does not recognize string interpolation therefore u need to use this construction: 
    `[attr.data-target]="'#popup_' + index"`

Comment: Bam! That's it! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, same goes for [attr.aria-whatever] attributes :)